# Javascript... simple question how to keep the form on the page after submitting

Tags: javascript, forms

Please see following example code that takes a year and a date and displays the data back when submitted...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JavaScript</title>   
</head>
<body>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
Enter the year to start from (eg: 2006): <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="year" VALUE=""><P>
Enter starting day (eg: 1= 1st Jan): <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="day" VALUE=""><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Go!" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
</FORM>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function testResults (form) {

  var years = form.year.value;
  var days = form.day.value;



   for (var x = days; x <= 365; x++)
   {

        for (var y = years; y <= 2010; y++)

        {

        document.write('  ValueY='+y+'ValueX='+x+'  ')

        }
    document.write("<br />");


}

}

function to3P(n){
return (n/100).toFixed(2).replace(/\./, '');
};
</SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to work out is how to LEAVE the form on the page after the document.write happens..(so the user doesn't have to keep pressing back to try new data!

Comment: You don't need to SHOUT ELEMENT NAMES these days :)

Comment: Leave... means that it stays on the page after the button is clicked

Comment: As previously stated, create a div where you will store your results. Then just append to innerHTML each time you want to output something.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using an example from 1995 to write your HTML... You should just read over some more modern html/javascript tutorials.  Just a few good things to clean up:

1. The language="javascript" attribute is depricated.  You only need to specify `<script
   type="text/javascript">`
2. It's better
   to use lowercase in your element
   declarations (ie: `<p>` instead of
   `<P>`)
3. For every element that you
   open, you need to close.  So for
   each `<p>`, you need a `</p>`.  If there
   is no closing tag, ie, it is
   self-closing, as with the `<br>`
   tag, you should write it: `<br />`,
   just like you did in the
   document.write code.  This makes
   your code truly XHTML compliant as
   you have specified in your doctype.
4. As already stated, no reason to pass in the form to the javascript function.  And just access the elements by id and their values via innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use document.write - if you use it after the page loads, you're essentially creating a new document.  You can either use the javascript DOM functions or just a

```
<div id="results"></div>


<script> document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "Your text here"; </script>
```

Comment: Might want to change the comma to a fullstop before innerHTML!

Comment: document.getElementById('results'),innerHTML should be 

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML  (with period)

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` is to blame. You should normally avoid it at all costs in favour of DOM manipulation and AJAX techniques. See [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blwrite.htm) and [here](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2005/06/21/six-javascript-features-we-do-not-need-any-longer/) and particularly [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-WCAG20-SCRIPT-TECHS-20041119/#doc-write) and there's a metric ton of coverage on this subject around the web.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write in a div instead of the document, the form will still be visible

```
<input TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Go!" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
<div id="myResult/>
```

and in the javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myResult').innerHTML = 'your text here'
```